# How to check if a list is in a list of lists

Tags: python

So the lists in list 'a' represent 2 people that are friends. Because friendships normally work both ways I made list1 and list2 for this. When I test my function it gives True as return-value for every of these 4 but only the first should be True and I don't understand why.
Thanks in advance.

```
def is_friend_with(name_person1, name_person2):
    list1 = [name_person1, name_person2]
    list2 = [name_person2, name_person1]
    if list1 or list2 in a:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(is_friend_with("Lucas", "Emma") )  # true
print(is_friend_with("Lucas", "Kevin") )  # false
print(is_friend_with("Suzy", "Emma") )  # false
print(is_friend_with("Suzy", "Frank") )  # false

a = [['Marie', 'Lucas'], ['Lucas', 'Patsy'], ['Emma', 'Lucas'], ['Emma', 'Kevin'], ['Peter', 'Emma'], ['Peter', 'Lucas'], ['Peter', 'Julie'], ['Suzy', 'Tobias']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your `if` statement. Currently that is checking if `list1` exists (which it always will) or if `list2` is in `a`. The if statement should be `if list1 in a or list2 in a:`

Here is the full solution.

```py
a = [['Marie', 'Lucas'], ['Lucas', 'Patsy'], ['Emma', 'Lucas'], ['Emma', 'Kevin'], ['Peter', 'Emma'], ['Peter', 'Lucas'], ['Peter', 'Julie'], ['Suzy', 'Tobias']]
def is_friend_with(name_person1, name_person2):
    list1 = [name_person1, name_person2]
    list2 = [name_person2, name_person1]
    if list1 in a or list2 in a:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(is_friend_with("Lucas", "Emma") )  # true
print(is_friend_with("Lucas", "Kevin") )  # false
print(is_friend_with("Suzy", "Emma") )  # false
print(is_friend_with("Suzy", "Frank") )  # false
```